# How to hide a div on document ready, and then call it dynamically from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to hide a div container where I'm placing text dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".slidingDiv").hide(); 
     $(".show_hide").show();

     $('.show_hide').click(function(){
         $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
     });
 });
```

The problem I have is that I want to trigger the show `div` from a javascript function instead of a predefined click event. I've found this example which mateches the function I want, but I'm not sure how to trigger it from javascript instead of a click function.

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/z9BXm/)

Comment: set-timeout and setTimeinterval is the function that will allow to call function after some periodic time set in it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just hide the div using css

```
display:none;

.slidingDiv{
 display:none;
}
```

and show it when ever you want using

```
.show()

$(".slidingDiv").show();
```

edit:

after you question edit, you can always trigger the click event programatically like

```
function yourFunction(){
  $(".show_hide").click();
}
```

Comment: could you adapt the jsfiddle to illustrate this?

Comment: This doesn't incorporate the slide open. I think because of the css element.

Comment: what problem do  you have with ur current solution? can you make a fiddle explaining the problem u are facing while showing and hiding the element

Answer (score 0):

At any point in your script you can call the `jQuery` object with your `div`'s id/class and run the `show()` function. i.e.

```
var javascript = "cool";
var foo = "I'm doing stuff";
var bar = "And some more stuff";
if (javascript === "cool") 
    jQuery(".slidingDiv").show();
else 
    $(".slidingDiv").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
         <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[type='file']").on("change", function () {
         if(this.files[0].size > 1000000) //file size less than 1MB { 
             {
          
                $("#fileAlert").show(); //calling a bootstrap 4 alert
             }
        
          $(this).val('');
         }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: could you please add some explanation to your answer?